# Subtracting and updating alphanumeric string in ms access

Tags: c#

I am designing an inventory system where I am supposed to update stock every time a product is sold. My stock column looks as below:

Stock
350 mts
500 pcs
750 mts
1000 mts

Now my requirement can be split into two parts,

1. how do I subtract this alphanumeric string from the quantity sold,
2. while updating unit should also appear in DB along with the number.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Why are you storing it like this? Would it not be easier to store the units separately to the count?

Comment: Thanks a lot John your input really helped me, it just did not strike me until you mentioned it . Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Stock 350 mts 500 pcs 750 mts 1000 mts";
            // any word characters followed by any white spaces
            // followed by any number of digits
            string pattern = @"(?'name'\w+)\s+(?'quantity'\d+)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name : '{0}', Qnty : '{1}'", match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["quantity"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```